# php sscanf problem

Tags: php, string, extract, scanf

I have this string:

```
City Lat/Lon: (50.7708) / (6.1053)
```

and I try to extract those two numbers with sscanf in php this way:

```
$result = post_request('http://www.ip-address.org/lookup/ip-locator.php', $post_data);
$start =strpos($result['content'], "City Lat/Lon");
$end = strpos($result['content'], "IP Language");
$sub = substr($result['content'],$start,$end-$start);
sscanf($sub, "City Lat/Lon: (%f) / (6.1053)",$asd);
echo $asd;
```

but it doesn't give me any result nor errors what should I change?

it works though this way

```
sscanf("City Lat/Lon: (50.7708) / (6.1053)", "City Lat/Lon: (%f) / (%f)",$asd,$wer);
```

Comment: Provide your code for assigning `$sub`.

Comment: I think your code is right for `sscanf`. Your problem is the parsing of your Lat/Long data. Do an `echo $sub;` and to ensure it's what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're using the `post_request()` function found [here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm).

If so, your `$sub` variable contains various HTML tags found in the response. For example if you attempt:

```
var_dump($sub) // Outputs: string 'City Lat/Lon:</th><td class='lookup'> (50.7708) / (6.1053)</td></tr><tr><th>' (length=78)
```

Instead of sscanf, you can try to match the latitude and longitude using a regular expression (as suggested by @Headshota). For example one possible solution:

```
//...

preg_match('#\((?<lat>-?[0-9.]+)\) / \((?<lon>-?[0-9.]+)\)#', $sub, $matches);
echo $matches["lat"]; // Outputs 50.7708
echo $matches["lon"]; // Outputs 6.1053
```

Comment: I actually just googled `post_request` because I had no idea what it was ;)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
$sub = 'City Lat/Lon: (50.7708) / (6.1053)';
var_dump( sscanf($sub, "City Lat/Lon: (%f) / (6.1053)",$asd), $asd);
```

... prints:

```
int(1)
float(50.7708)
```

The error can be in your exact test code or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex:

```
 preg_match_all("/(\([0-9.]+\))/");
```

this will return an array with your values.